# jtextfield increment by 1. when click submit button

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am using `Netbeans 7.2.1`. and MS SQL 2008, connection via ODBC.

I am making a small retail shop application.

I want to be able click submit button then  my bill_number(using jtextfield) auto increment by 1.

Comment: Show your attempt so far and prove that you have minimal understanding of the problem being solved

Comment: what is your question then?

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your submit button action listener, changing textField to the appropriate JTextField instance:

```
        String s = textField.getText();
        int billNumber = Integer.valueOf(s);
        s = Integer.toString(++billNumber);
        textField.setText(s);
```